# How to set min weight in sphinx API?

Tags: php, sphinx

How do I set a minimum weight in the sphinx API?

I want to find all the rows whose weight is greater than say, 20.

Answer (score 1):

Just call [setFilterFloatRange](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-0.9.9.html#api-func-setfilterfloatrange) like

```
$q->SetFilterFloatRange('@weight', 20, 999999, true);
```

Comment: I got this error: no such filter attribute '@weight'. I'm sorry but I haven't been able to access the sphinx website for days, dunno what's going on, so I'm stuck.

Comment: if you set compat_sphinxql_magic option to 0 you have to alias weight(*) first then use it within filer like `SELECT *, WEIGT(*) as w from YOUR_INDEX where w>20`

Comment: Is that a new feature or what? I can't seem to make it work. I keep geting errors like 'unknown identifier weight', 'weight is not a function', 'unexpected *)', etc. My sphinx version is 0.9.9

Comment: $q->SetFilterFloatRange('@weight', 20, 999999, true); will exclude records having wieght > 20 use $q->SetFilterFloatRange('@weight', 20, 999999) instead.